# Protecting data in file geodatabase (making read-only)?

Tags: file-geodatabase

What kind of steps can I take to protect data in a file gdb, or even the entire gdb, so that it can't be modified inadvertently? (e.g. by a tool like Rubbersheet that modifies data in place.)

I understand the file-gdb does not have the concept of users or permissions, and that to use those we must use an RDBMS. What's the best I can do, given that using file-gdb is a requirement?

Note: I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 but did not tag the question that way as some answers may be relevant to other platforms.

Comment: In the past, setting access rules on the parent folder in which the file geo-database is placed allowed me to control access to file gdbs, did you try that?

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.1, you can create a [licensed file geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-licensed-file-geodatabase.htm) to restrict access to the contents.

> Generates a license definition file (.licdef) that defines and
>   restricts the display of contents in a file geodatabase. The contents
>   of the licensed file geodatabase can be viewed by creating a license
>   file (*.sdlic) and installing it with ArcGIS Administrator.

**edit:** As Vince points out below, FGDB API tools would not honor the licensed geodatabase. The ESRI blog [issues this warning](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/13/file-geodatabase-api-details/):

> The API will not prevent users from attempting to edit objects with
>   complex behavior, the onus will be on the developer to understand what
>   they should and should not edit through the API and avoid editing
>   datasets that have geodatabase behavior.

Since a FGDB is just a folder on disk with some binary files in it, I think strict folder permissions is probably the best you can do.

Comment: The File Geodatabase API doesn't read licensed geodatabases, so this solution would create a *write-only* geodatabase with respect to apps using FileGBDAPI.dll.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about licensed file gdb's. I'm not able to create one though, Error 000260 followed by 001638; guess I've another question to post after I've done some more research and testing.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what is needed [Compress File Geodatabase Data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/compress-file-geodatabase-data.htm) might work. For example feature classes in a compressed gdb cannot be edited and field properties not modified. For the full list see [Restrictions when working with compressed data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/compress-file-geodatabase-data.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3A5D414FDFD44E24835DD2867CA76D5F).

Initially I though the Rubbersheet geoprocessing tool was perfectly happy to modify compressed data, as it says it completes successfully. Inspection after the fact reveals it did not in fact make any changes. Moral of the story: you need to disbelieve the results messages and verify when working with compressed data and gp tools.

Thanks to @Mintx for the f-gdb licensing answer, as it led me to compress file-gdb in the same toolbox section. :)